# Working out indoor, I need advice what equipment to use as replacement to gym equipment

Tags: gym, exercise-equipment

I can't often go to the gym for many factors (weather, time and other matters). Although, I want to continue working out in my apartment instead. Since I'm new in working out to the gym, I am not sure what equipment I should store at home that would help me in working out. Can you advice what equipment should I buy as an alternative equipment to what I used in the gym.

Equipment I used at the Gym:

- **Bench Press** - My room is really small, so, I can't store the bench and the barbel
- **Squats** - I use the cage and the barbel in the gym; And can't store them again.
- **Cable Row**
- **Abdominal Crunch Machine**
- **Assisted Pull up Machine**
- **Treadmill**

Most of this machine are really big and expensive at the same time. I'm looking for an affordable alternatives where I can easily store them under my bed.

Comment: What exactly is your goal? You aren't going to be a powerlifter without a rack, nor will you be a runner without going running, etc... What does "being fit" mean to you?

Comment: Calisthenics can give it all. Moreover, you become more agile with it.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I think my goal is having a good tone body and perhaps a body of an athlete. I just learned about Calisthenics and it it's interesting. I just need to findout how to get started with it. Thanks for all your insights guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Calisthenics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calisthenics)

if you look youtube you will find loads of alternatives

You can look at this for a start

[Introduction](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X88VqEgMpsY)

[Some workout alternatives for gym](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VEtBsY8b5Xw)

Also for **Treadmill** you can use **Jump Ropes**

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how big/motivated you are, you might have to modify your workout. If your room is too small for a bench, you cannot perform bench-related exercises; however, you can perform other exercises that should compensate for those. 
 
**Benchpress** focuses on the chest; **pushups** and ***(unsure what the name is, but you lie on your back and lift dumbbells from your sides)*** are alternatives. 
 
**Squats** can be done anywhere, with or without dumbbells. 
 
**Abdominal crunches** can be done on the floor. 
 
**Pull ups** can be done on doors.  
 
**Treadmill** (to me is a waste of time); get videos such as **Insanity** or **P90X** for high intensity exercises. 
 
In this day and age, gym going isn't a necessity for staying in shape. 
 
And always try to read more and staying motivated :).

Comment: @Pennf0lio you are very welcome; hope it helps :).